# function in foreach loop duplicating returned values when saving to an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a foreach loop running a script that simply calls a database and stores the returned array to another array. The script below,

```
foreach( $default_fields as $defKey => $defVal ) {
        if(in_array( $defVal->display_name, $this->_connection_data->formula )) {
            $endpoints[$defVal->display_name] = $this->$addon_field->{$defVal->function_name}($addon_guid);
        }
        $display_name[] = $defVal->display_name;
    }
```

$default_fields contains the below array,

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [display_name] => Other Income
        [function_name] => otherIncome
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [display_name] => Income
        [function_name] => income
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [display_name] => Current Liabilities
        [function_name] => currentLiabilities
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [display_name] => Non Current Liabilities
        [function_name] => nonCurrentLiabilities
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [display_name] => Current Assets
        [function_name] => currentAssets
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [display_name] => Non Current Assets
        [function_name] => nonCurrentAssets
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [display_name] => Equity
        [function_name] => equity
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [display_name] => Cost of Sales
        [function_name] => costOfSales
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [display_name] => Expenses
        [function_name] => expenses
    )

[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [display_name] => Other Expenses
        [function_name] => otherExpenses
    )

[10] => stdClass Object
    (
        [display_name] => Closing Bank
        [function_name] => closingBalanceBankAccounts
    )
```

$this->_connection_data->formula contains this,

```
[0] => (
[1] => Income
[2] => +
[3] => Other Income
[4] => )
[5] => -
[6] => Cost of Sales
```

When I run the functions ($defVal->function_name) outside of this loop, they return the correct values that are an array that contain 12 keys each, 0-11. When the loop runs as it is, for reasons I do not know or understand, The resulting $endpoints array looks something like the below,

```
Array
   (
    [Other Income] => Array
      (
        [0] => function 1 results
        [1] => function 1 results
        [2] => function 1 results
        [3] => function 1 results
        [4] => function 1 results
        [5] => function 1 results
        [6] => function 1 results
        [7] => function 1 results
        [8] => function 1 results
        [9] => function 1 results
        [10] => function 1 results
        [11] => function 1 results
       )
     )
   [Income] => Array
     (
        [0] => function 1 results
        [1] => function 1 results
        [2] => function 1 results
        [3] => function 1 results
        [4] => function 1 results
        [5] => function 1 results
        [6] => function 1 results
        [7] => function 1 results
        [8] => function 1 results
        [9] => function 1 results
        [10] => function 1 results
        [11] => function 1 results
        [12] => function 2 results
        [13] => function 2 results
        [14] => function 2 results
        [15] => function 2 results
        [16] => function 2 results
        [17] => function 2 results
        [18] => function 2 results
        [19] => function 2 results
        [20] => function 2 results
        [21] => function 2 results
        [22] => function 2 results
        [23] => function 2 results
        ......
```

I am wanting to return the $endpoints array with each array in it to only contain  the function that was called at the times results, like so...

```
Array
   (
    [Other Income] => Array
      (
        [0] => function 1 results
        [1] => function 1 results
        [2] => function 1 results
        [3] => function 1 results
        [4] => function 1 results
        [5] => function 1 results
        [6] => function 1 results
        [7] => function 1 results
        [8] => function 1 results
        [9] => function 1 results
        [10] => function 1 results
        [11] => function 1 results
       )
     )
   [Income] => Array
     (
        [0] => function 2 results
        [1] => function 2 results
        [2] => function 2 results
        [3] => function 2 results
        [4] => function 2 results
        [5] => function 2 results
        [6] => function 2 results
        [7] => function 2 results
        [8] => function 2 results
        [9] => function 2 results
        [10] => function 2 results
        [11] => function 2 results
        ......
```

Has anyone got an idea on where I have gone wrong in this process ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Added the function body as requested...

```
$data = $this->_dbuser->query('SELECT account,type,month_1,month_2,month_3,month_4,month_5,month_6,month_7,month_8,month_9,month_10,month_11,month_12 FROM db_calculate WHERE integration_guid = ?',array($guid));
    if (!empty($data->results())) {
        $data = $data->results();

        $dates = $this->_dbuser->query('SELECT month_1,month_2,month_3,month_4,month_5,month_6,month_7,month_8,month_9,month_10,month_11,month_12 FROM db_calculate_months WHERE integration_guid = ? ',array($guid));
        if ($dates->results()) {
            $dates = $dates->results()[0];

            $array = array(); $count = 0;
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                for ($start = 1; $start <= 12; $start ++) {
                    $holder = 'month_'.$start;
                    $array[$count]['account'] = $row->account;
                    $array[$count]['type'] = $row->type;
                    $array[$count]['total'] = $row->$holder;
                    $array[$count]['to_date'] = $dates->$holder;
                    $count ++;
                }
            }


        }
    }

    $filter = array(); $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $arr) {
        if ($arr['type'] == "Income") {
            $filter[$count]['account'] = $arr['account'];
            $filter[$count]['total'] = $arr['total'];
            $filter[$count]['to_date'] = $arr['to_date'];
            $count ++;
        }
    }

    $results = array($filter[0]); $count = 1;
    foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {
        if ($key > 0) {
            $pos = array_search($value['to_date'],array_column($results, 'to_date'));
            if (in_array($value['to_date'],array_column($results,'to_date'))) {
                $results[$pos]['total'] = $results[$pos]['total'] + $value['total'];
                $count ++;
            } else {
                $results[$count] = $value;
                $count ++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
$endpoints[$defVal->display_name][] = $this->$addon_field->{$defVal->function_name}($addon_guid);
```

instead of :

```
$endpoints[$defVal->display_name] = $this->$addon_field->{$defVal->function_name}($addon_guid);
```

Comment: or might be `$endpoints[$defVal->display_name][$addon_guid] = $this->$addon_field->{$defVal->function_name}($addon_guid);`

Comment: Thanks FatemehNB, but this only adds another array depth, it does not stop the duplication of the function results when saving to the array.

Comment: maybe problem is in your functions body? is it possible to put them in your question?

Comment: I have added the functions body, the only difference between the functions is the data filtered in the $filter array. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I suggest you to check body of your functions to be asuured that youdid not put duplicate `if condition` for filter array.